# elasticsearch using NEST: How to use document versioning?

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I am using elasticsearch and accessing it from C# through the NEST driver. I need to do some concurrency control on the documents I am adding and updating through the NEST driver. [Here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/2011/02/08/versioning.html) is a link to the corresponding elasticsearch feature, but I am unable to find any information on how to use document versioning with the NEST driver.

I attempted to set up a [mapping](http://mpdreamz.github.com/NEST/indices/put-mapping.html), hoping the "_version" property would deserialize from the indexed document (without serializing), but no luck.

Has anyone been able to do what I am trying to do? Is this even possible?

Comment: For those coming to this later, I have written an article on using Optimistic Concurrency with Elasticsearch and NEST - http://forloop.co.uk/blog/optimistic-concurrency-with-elasticsearch-and-nest

Comment: Excellent article. That is exactly what I ended up doing when I encountered this issue almost 3 years ago. I even authored NEST's OpType support to make it work. Glad somebody else found it useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_version` is a meta data attribute that you can access using `result.DocumentsWithMetaData` this exposes an `IEnumerable<Hit<YourDto>>` and `Hit<YourDto>>` has a `.Version` property.

Elasticsearch will automatically increase the version number if none is specified.

You can specify your own expected version when you index see the tests here:
https://github.com/Mpdreamz/NEST/blob/master/src/Nest.Tests.Unit/Core/Versioning/VersioningTests.cs

From the ES docs i have not been able to find a mention on how to specify the expected version on the `GET` and `Script Update` API. Will have to dive in deeper to be absolutely sure it's not needed there.

The `op_type` create mentioned on http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/2011/02/08/versioning.html is not supported, will also get that in for the next release.